# Use R within Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, kernel, r, jupyter-notebook

I am using the Jupyter notebook to create interactive code sheets in Python. Now that I have to work with R, I'm wondering: Can I use Jupyter notebook to compile R code as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, even though Jupyter was originally designed for python, it supports R among a whole bunch of other programming languages.

In order for a programming language to be compiled correctly in the notebook, the corresponding kernel has to be installed. You'll find the [R-Kernel](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel) under the name "IRkernel" with [installation instructions](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel#installation) on github.

Once you installed the kernel, you should be able to select it from a dropdown menu in the notebook.
If you want to start an interface with R kernel, use the `--kernel=` parameter:

```
# “ir” is the kernel name installed by the above `IRkernel::installspec()`
# change if you used a different name!
jupyter qtconsole --kernel=ir
jupyter console --kernel=ir
```